# Integrating MongoDB with django?

Tags: django, mongodb

so I have a MongoDB database with data I collected. I want to take this data and send it in as a rest api, however I can't seem to find any engine to run mongodb using django that was made recently and for the current version of django. Does anyone know of such a library or can direct me to a recent django project that integrates Mongo successfully because I can't find any.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. [pymongo](https://pypi.org/project/pymongo/)
2. [django-rest-framework-mongoengine](https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/)
3. [mongoengine](https://pypi.org/project/mongoengine/)

#### sample of code

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, URLField, EmbeddedDocumentListField
from mongoengine.errors import ValidationError
from forms import Form

class ModelData(Document):
  """Document representing a service."""
  name = StringField(required=True)
  category = StringField(required=True)
  provider = StringField(required=True)
  forms = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Form, required=True)
  meta = {
    'indexes': [
      {'fields': ('name', 'category', 'provider'), 'unique': True},
      'name',
      'category',
      'provider'
    ]
  }
```

Have a nice trip [here](https://medium.com/@vasjaforutube/django-mongodb-django-rest-framework-mongoengine-ee4eb5857b9a)

Comment: I am trying to use these three tools. But what things I have to change in settings.py . I mean do I have to change database engine and name.

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option to use [djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/get-started/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Djongo engine for integrating Django and MYSQL.

Step1:

```
pip install djongo
pip install mongoengine
```

Step2:
in settings.py replace DATABASES variable with the below code

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
  'ENGINE': 'djongo',
  'NAME' : 'Collection NAME',
  'HOST' : 'localhost'
 }
}
```

Step3:

```
run python manage.py migrate
```